# Limit rotation doesn't work properly

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm working with car animation. I parented brakes to the wheels and add "limit rotation" for X and Y axis

[image]

And its work fine when car moving along -Y direction

[image]

But flickering from 0 to 180° on z axis when moving along +Y direction

[image]

Is there any other solution to limit rotation on X and Y and keep Z rotation?